# How to change CSS margin of a string value if value is larger then 99 inside a span tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to change CSS margin of a string when its value is > than 99 inside a `<span>` tag?

How do I achieve this?

```css
.total_quantity {
  position         : absolute;
  z-index          : 1;
  background-color : transparent;
  font-family      : cute-font;
  font-size        : 40px;
  animation        : neonAnim 2s alternate-reverse infinite;
  color            : #FF00F0;
/* Default Value */
  margin-right     : 2px;
/* I want to change the CSS margin to the below value when it's > 99 */
  margin-right     : 20px;
  }
```

```html
<span class="total_quantity">99</span>
```

---

I am actually getting data from JS function here is my code for the function

```
function pos_total_row() {
     var total_quantity = 0;
     $('table#pos_table tbody tr').each(function() {
         total_quantity = total_quantity + __read_number(
            $(this).find('input.pos_quantity')    
         );
     });
     $('span.total_quantity').each(function() {
         $(this).html(__number_f(total_quantity));
     });
}
```

Comment: You added JS and jquery to your tags  That sounds like a reasonable way to do it.  Specifically: 1) add an "id" to the element with "99" (the element you want to read), 2) Invoke some JS on page load ("$( document ).ready()" is a Pop Favorite), 3) read your value (e.g. "99") and update your class CSS (e.g. "total_quantity") programmatically (either jQuery or vanilla JS, in the onload procedure).

Comment: I am actually getting data from JS function here is my code for the function `function pos_total_row() {
    var total_quantity = 0;
    $('table#pos_table tbody tr').each(function() {
        total_quantity = total_quantity + __read_number($(this).find('input.pos_quantity'));
    });


    $('span.total_quantity').each(function() {
        $(this).html(__number_f(total_quantity));
    });
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a variable to put inside the tag; you would create it in JavaScript, then use an if statement to ask whether the variable is >99.
You could then create another CSS class, one that handles >99 and one that handles <99, where the code is the same except for the margins. Sorry that is not efficient. Then based on the JavaScript if statement, you either put the variable inside the tag of the <99 or >99 class.

Comment: Your solution seems to me the good one can you give me some working example?

Comment: So sorry, but not really! This computer is a temporary loan and cannot download any coding software. That answer was pulled out of a theoretical realm, but you would not want to see a solution made without the help of the syntax correction that a code editor gives! Nonetheless, glad to hear that it is useful on a logical basis. Try to take that logic and see if you can create a working example based on its premise.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways I am trying to get into the working solution.